# How to correctly format this line?

Tags: delphi

I have

```
strDamage := format(SEND_DAMAGE_DATA_TEMPLATE,HowMuchDamage,WhatGetsDamaged);
```

strDamage is a string of course
HowmuchDamge and WhatGetsDamaged is integers.

I know i have to convert  intToString() but what would the format be to do this?
example  `Send_Damage_Data_Template := 'pd%s';`

if they where strings then it would send
pd[howmuchdamage][whatgetsdamage]  as a string.. but with them being integers how do i set this up?

UPDATE.

pd is just the protocol code so server knows what to do with it

```
        procedure TCardcommunicator.SendDamage(HowMuchDamage : integer; WhatGetsDamaged : integer);
    var
      strDamage : string;
    begin
      strDamage := format(SEND_DAMAGE_DATA_TEMPLATE,HowMuchDamage,WhatGetsDamaged);
      FBackEnd.Send(format(SEND_DAMAGE_PKT_TEMPLATE,[length(strDamage),strDamage]));
    end;

  SEND_DAMAGE_DATA_TEMPLATE = 'pd%d%d';
  SEND_DAMAGE_PKT_TEMPLATE  = 'pd%.4d%s'+ chr(13) + chr(10);
```

I get error saying there is no overload for format on the line for strDamgae;

Comment: This makes little sense. The code does not compile. The format string has one rather than two place holders. What is pd%s? Please clarify.

Comment: pd is just the code i send to the server so it knows what to do with the string.

Comment: Your error line **does not do** what I told you to do. **Read my code sample** more carefully, and read every single character in the call to `Format`. Especially the two `[]` characters, which are missing from your code.

Comment: I dont feel close is being used for what it was suppose to be used for here...

Comment: @Glen You don't like the votes to close? Try putting some effort into [asking your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I voted to close because your question is unclear: You were vague about what you were trying to achieve. It's not clear where you were struggling. Ken was forced to provide a fairly general answer which is basically covered in Delphi documentation. You put almost zero effort into asking your question and even less in following Ken's advice. As such I don't see how this Q&A will be of value to anyone else.

Comment: I would also like to ask: Are you by any chance sharing this account with someone else? I find it difficult to belieive that [your answer on 23 Oct](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19532408/224704) and this question (over a month later) were written by the same person.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NOTE: This answer was posted to the original form of the question, not the edited version which has actual code. See the revision history.

I'm not sure what the content of `SEND_DAMAGE_DATA_TEMPLATE` represents as stated with `pd%s', as`%s` is a string specifier. For clarity, if it contains:

```
SEND_DAMAGE_DATA_TEMPLATE = 'Damage: %d  Location: %d';
```

The `%d` format specifiers indicate that it's expecting two integer values.

You can then format it like this:

```
strDamage := Format(SEND_DAMAGE_DATA_TEMPLATE, [ HowMuchDamage, 
                                                 WhatGetsDamaged ]);
```

`%d` is the format specifier for integers.

The [`Format`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE5/en/SysUtilsFormat_%28Delphi%29) function [`Format Strings`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.SysUtils.Format) are pretty clearly documented, with a fairly good [example](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE5/en/SysUtilsFormat_%28Delphi%29) as well.

Comment: yes this is what i was looking for.. so if i send the format like this it will convert the integers to strings correct?

Comment: @Glen Why did you not read the documentation? It's clear. There are examples. Why do you not attempt to help yourself? I know you are capable of doing so. It just seems lazy not to even read the documentation.

Comment: @KenWhite  So if `HowMuchDamge := 5` and `WhatGetsDamaged := 3`  it would send pd53 as a string correct?

Comment: @Glen: Clearly, yes. The `Format` function **always** returns a string, so in order to put two integer values in that result it would have to convert them to strings. I'm not sure how that's unclear.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks,  I was not sure if i had to add %s at the end or something to tell it to send it as a string.

Comment: @Glen: Clearly, with the example I posted, passing the values of `5` and `3` would return `Damage: 5 Location: 3`.

Comment: I still get errors.. :(  If ok ill update post

Comment: @Glen: Change your string to contain two `%d` values, **just like I showed you**. If you want the string to be `d: 5 l: 3`, make the string `d: %d l: %d`, and pass the values **exactly** like I showed you in my code.