# Function with unlimited arguments

Tags: pascal

I don't know if it's possible do this as I want.

I have a function in Pascal which prints text on screen with some exclusive format.

```
    procedure printLine(line1:string;line2:string;line3:string;line4:string;line5:string);
begin
    writeln('**** ',line1,' ',line2,' ',line3,' ',line4,' ',line5);
end;
```

I want to know if there's a method to make it look like writeln and call it with the number of arguments I need.

Comment: Probably easiest would be to code your `printLine` to accept a linked list of text lines; that way, the list can contain an arbitrary number of lines.

Comment: See [array of const](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Variant_Open_Array_Parameters)

Comment: @LURD: That is a Delphi (and FreePascal, I guess) construct. It does not exist for every Pascal, AFAIK.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, yes Delphi and Freepascal. Allen commented the background history: [A look at "array of const" for fun and profit](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/a-look-at-array-of-const-for-fun-and-profit-35293).

Comment: Yeah, the Turbo Vision (TP) formatstr() function is gory, the delphi object pascal version is much better

Answer (score 0):

I was working in the answer of this question. I'm not going to use it on my program, but I will post what I made.

```
procedure printLine(const Args: array of const);
var
    i:integer;
begin
write('**** '); 
for i:=0 to High(Args) do
        write(args[i],' ');
    writeln;
end;
```

This is the code using the const array of Delphi in case someone needs it. **I didn't test it.** This solution was made based on the comment of *LU RD*.

About the comment of *MartynA*:
I defined quickly an Unit based on a dinamic queue of Strings. I checked it and implemented the new procedure **printLine**. 
The implementation of the procedure with this Queue is:

```
procedure printLine(Args:tQueue);
var
begin
    write('**** ');
    while (not(isEmptyQueue(Args))) do begin
        write(front(Args));
        dequeue(Args);
    writeln;
end;
```

I realised the question I made was pretty simple to solve but I was 
a bit tired when asked that.
Thanks to all.

Comment: You will have to convert the `Args` elements to string, for example using `VarRecToString` found in this answer: [How do I build an array of const?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19532408/576719).

Comment: Or use the `RTTI` unit and transform the `TVarRec` element to a `TValue` in order to convert to a string: `TValue.FromVarRec(args[i]).ToString`

Comment: Write can print elements which are not a string, like integers.

Comment: At least, I thought it worked like that. I said i hadn't tested that, if someone tests it and doesn't work, please report and I'll change it. Thanks LU RD for your attention.

Comment: The proposed changes will work for most types. For printing through `Write`, the type must be known at compile time, hence the explicit conversion to string.

Comment: Wow, I understand. I never worked on Delphi and I didn't know. Later I change the code and add the RTTI unit like the post you show me. Thanks LU RD.