# Delphi RIO - Ansi to string cast does not work when Ansi string is part of array of const

Tags: delphi

I'm using Delphi RIO 10.3.3.

When I pass Ansi string as one of the elements of array of const, string() cast does not work on it. To make it work, I have to cast VAnsiString to AnsiString() first and then apply String() cast.

Most of the similar examples I have seen on net, use direct String() casting.

Is it a bug in RIO or am I missing something?

```
function TForm1.VarRecToStr(AVarRec: TVarRec): string;
  const
    Bool : array[Boolean] of string = ('False', 'True');
begin
    case AVarRec.VType of
      vtInteger:    Result := IntToStr(AVarRec.VInteger);
      vtBoolean:    Result := Bool[AVarRec.VBoolean];
      vtChar:       Result := AVarRec.VChar;
      vtExtended:   Result := FloatToStr(AVarRec.VExtended^);
      vtString:     Result := AVarRec.VString^;
      vtPChar:      Result := AVarRec.VPChar;
      vtObject:     Result := AVarRec.VObject.ClassName;
      vtClass:      Result := AVarRec.VClass.ClassName;
      //vtAnsiString: Result := string(AnsiString(AVarRec.VAnsiString));
      vtAnsiString: Result := string(AVarRec.VAnsiString);
      vtCurrency:   Result := CurrToStr(AVarRec.VCurrency^);
      vtVariant:    Result := string(AVarRec.VVariant^);
      vtWideString: Result := string(WideString(AVarRec.VWideString));
      vtUnicodeString:
                    Result := string(AVarRec.VUnicodeString);
    else
      result := '';
    end;
end;


function TForm1.VarArrayToStr(AVarArray: array of const): string;
  var
    i : integer;
begin
    result := '';
    for i := 0 to High(AVarArray) do
      result := result + VarRecToStr( AVarArray[i] );
end;


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  w: WideString;
  s: shortstring;
  an: Ansistring;
begin
  //
  w := 'Wide';
  s := 'Short';
  an := 'Ansi';
  ShowMessage(VarArrayToStr([w,s,an, 10]));
end;
```

Output:

[image]

Code credits to: [How do I build an array of const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532228/how-do-i-build-an-array-of-const/19532408#19532408)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like `UnicodeString` and `WideString`, an `AnsiString` is stored in a `TVarRec` as an *untyped* pointer to its data payload.  You have to cast that pointer to `AnsiString` (or at least to `PAnsiChar`) in order for the RTL to access the `AnsiString`'s data properly (including its `StrRec` header, if needed).  You are trying to type-cast the untyped `Pointer` *as-is* directly to `UnicodeString`, which will not work.  The compiler will accept that, but it will assume the pointer is to a `UnicodeString`'s payload, not to an `AnsiString`'s payload.  As such, you need to type-cast the pointer to `PAnsiChar` or `AnsiString` so that the RTL knows to convert the data from ANSI to Unicode during the assignment to a `UnicodeString`.

Comment: Thanks, Remy for the explaination... But this makes me wonder, in this case, Emb's own example will not work as it is, at least for Ansi string as an element in the array: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Variant_Open_Array_Parameters

Comment: @NamoRamana Correct, the example is wrong.  It would have worked as shown when `string` was still `AnsiString` prior to D2009, or even in D2009 and D2010 when `UnicodeString` supported ANSI payloads.  But since XE, that example as shown will not work anymore, no (the example is also missing a few `case` blocks for `WideChar`/`WideString` data).  I have [submitted a ticket](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-30470) for this.